# EF Caching: How to detach objects *completely* before inserting them into HttpRuntime cache?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, caching, memory-leaks, entity-framework-5

### **Some background:**

**Working with:**

- .NET 4.5 (*thinking of migrating to 4.5.1 if it's painless*)
- Web Forms
- Entity Framework 5, Lazy Loading enabled
- Context Per Request
- IIS 8
- Windows 2012 Datacenter

**Point of concern**: Memory Usage

Over the project we are currently on, and probably our first bigger project, we're often reading some bigger chunks of data, coming from CSV imports, that are likely to stay the same for very long periods of time.

Unless someone explicitly re-imports the CSV data, they are guaranteed to be the same, this happens in more than one places in our project and similar approach is used for some regular documents that are often being read by the users. We've decided to cache this data in the HttpRuntime cache.

It goes like this, and we pull about 15,000 records consisting mostly of strings.

```
//myObject and related methods are placeholders
public static List<myObject> GetMyCachedObjects()
{
    if (CacheManager.Exists(KeyConstants.keyConstantForMyObject))
    {
        return CacheManager.Get(KeyConstants.keyConstantForMyObject) as List<myObject>;
    }
    else
    {
        List<myObject> myObjectList = framework.objectProvider.GetMyObjects();
        CacheManager.Add(KeyConstants.keyConstantForMyObject, myObjectList, true, 5000);
        return myObjectList;
    }
}
```

The data retrieving for the above method is very simple and looks like this:

```
public List<myObject> GetMyObjects()
{
    return context.myObjectsTable.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

There are probably things to be said about the code structure, but that's not my concern at the moment.

I began profiling our project as soon as I saw high memory usage and found many parts where our code could be optimized. I never faced 300 simultaneous users before and our internal tests, done by ourselves were not enough to show the memory issues. I've highlighted and fixed numerous memory leaks but I'd like to understand some Entity Framework related unknowns.

Given the above example, and using ANTS Profiler, I've noticed that '**myObject**', and other similar objects, are referencing many **System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies**.myObject, additionally there are lots of **EntityKeys** which hold on to integers. They aren't taking much but their count is relatively high.

For instance 124 instances of '**myObject**' are referencing nearly 300 System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.

**Usually it looks like this, whatever the object is:**
Some cache entry, some object I've cached and I now noticed many of them have been detached from dbContext prior caching, the dynamic proxies and the objectContext. I've no idea how to untie them.

[image]

### **My progress:**

I did some research and found out that I might be caching something Entity Framework related together with those objects. I've pulled them with **NoTracking** but there are still those DynamicProxies in the memory which probably hold on to other things as well.

**Important:** I've observed some live instances of ObjectContext (74), slowly growing, but no instances of my unitOfWork which is holding the dbContext. Those seem to be disposed properly per request basis.

I know how to detach, attach or modify state of an entry from my dbContext, which is wrapped in a unitOfWork, and I often do it. However that doesn't seem to be enough or I am asking for the impossible.

### **Questions:**

- Basically, what am I doing wrong with my caching approach when it comes to Entity Framework?
- Is the growing number of Object Contexts in the memory a concern, I know the cache will eventually expire but I'm worried of open connections or anything else this context might be holding.
- Should I be detaching everything from the context before inserting it into the cache?
- If yes, what is the best approach. Especially with List I cannot think of anything else but iterating over the collection and call detach one by one.
- Bonus question: About 40% of the consumed memory is free (unallocated), I've no idea why .NET is reserving so much free memory in advance.

Comment: Do your objects reference other objects? That is, does `myObject` have a relationship to other objects in the database?

Comment: Well, lazy loading is enabled and they have some related tables. Just found out which objets hold onto the objectContexts, they are like 160 atm and they hold exactly all 160 objectContext through dynamic proxies.

Comment: I added a picture of what bothers me, from ANTS Profiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using non entity class with specific properties with SELECT method.

```
public class MyObject2 {
   public int ID { get; set; }  
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public List<MyObject2> GetObjects(){  
   return framework.provider.GetObjects().Select(
      x=> new MyObject2{
         ID = x.ID ,
         Name = x.Name
      }).ToList();
   );
}
```

Since you will be storing plain c# objects, you will not have to worry about dynamic proxies. You will not have to call detach on anything at all. Also you can store only few properties.

Even if you disable tracking, You will see dynamic proxy because EF uses dynamic class derived from your class which stores extra meta data information (relation e .g. name of foreign key etc to other entities) for the entity.

Comment: That sounds like a plausible solution indeed, but it would require a lot of rewriting and custom classes as the problem is not just at one place. Very useful for the future though. Isn't there a way to avoid that meta data information? Is it even a concern?

Comment: Metadata will always be present, I don't think it is concern. Each object will have one extra metadata per navigation property, but that just stores name of the relation etc. It does not need more memory. Also you don't need to detach, because it will stay like that even after detached and every entity will be detached automatically when your context is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

steps to reduce memory here:

- Re `new` the context, often 
   Dont try and delete content from the Context. Or Set it to detached.
   It hangs around like a fart in a phone box
   eg `context = new MyContext.`
  But if possible you should be

> using (var context = new Mycontext){ .... }
>   //short lived contexts is best practice

- With your Context you can set Configurations

> ```
>  this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;  
>  this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;   //<<<<<<<<<<< THIS one   
>  this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
> ```

you can disable proxies if you still feel they are hogging memory.
But that may be unecesseary if you apply `using` to the context in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your input, as stated, my context is disposed properly. I'm using context per request and there aren't any UoW hanging or dbContext hanging, they are being disposed at the end of the request. What happens if I disable proxy creation though? What's the downside?

Comment: I've read it up, it's a last-resort solution. The downsides are too many in the project's current state.

Answer (score -1):

I would redesign the solution a bit:

- You are storing all data as a single entry in cache

I would move this and have an entry per cache item.

- You are using HTTPRuntime cache

I would use Appfabric Caching, also MS, also free.

- Not sure where you are calling that code from

I would Call it on Application start, then all data is in memory when the user needs it

- You are using Entity SQL

For this I would use an Entity Data Reader http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entitydatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

See also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx

Comment: Hello, reading from the database is not an issue at all and the way I am accessing it is way more common than the suggested Entity Data Reader I am not aware of. I'm aware of performance considerations article and I'm using several techniques mentioned there.

I'll read up Appfabric Caching, thanks. However the answer, as much as useful it can be, is a bit out of topic, no offense.